# Wacom Intuos Touch disable button

Tags: ubuntu-touch, wacom

Running 14.04

I recently bought the Wacom Intuos Pen & Touch and it's working beautifully out of the box, however I often touch the tablet by mistake and it wreaks havoc...

So I figured out how to disable the function, and I know how to make that command permanent, however that's not really what I want as it seems really final and not a clean solution.

The command is this:

```
xsetwacom -v --set 'Wacom Intuos PT S Finger touch' gesture off
```

And to turn it back on:

```
xsetwacom -v --set 'Wacom Intuos PT S Finger touch' gesture on
```

What I would like to make is to have it as a script, and placed as a button on the taskbar (somewhere next to my clock) using which I can toggle it on and off whenever I need to turn it back on.

Can anyone help with this?
Cheers!

Comment: My tablet (it's a 480) has a small switch in the border (upper right) which *physically* disable touch. I am telling you because I found it after weeks of pain :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, with a co-workers help I have a script now that toggles the touch function on/off, now I'd like to be able to somehow make it as a custom indicator on the taskbar... here's the code for the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
device="Wacom Intuos PT S Finger touch"

state="`xsetwacom --get "$device" gesture`"
if [ "$state" = "on" ] ; then
    xsetwacom --set "$device" gesture off
    echo "gesture = off"
else
    xsetwacom --set "$device" gesture on
    echo "gesture = on"
fi
```

Comment: I do not know how to do it in Unity, but for gnome-shell you can leverage my extension to have a button to toggle focus: https://github.com/Rmano/gse-switch-focus-mode